# What is the mechanism of making folders with the same names in the same place?

Tags: windows-7

I happen to look into the folder `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2` and I see something like this：

[image]

There are many folders appear to have same name in the same place.
If I check the `Type`, I get:
[image]

The GUIDs are also reflected in the console:
[image]

Also, if I copy the folders outside from this `Installer2`, the GUIDs will appear. And If I create and move a folder with a trailing GUID into `Installer2`, the GUID will be hidden. But I don't see any system files in `Installer2` to control this, even after I uncheck the "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" in Folder Options. I see something in the Registry if I search `NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2` but I haven't looked into it and I am not sure whether it's the only way to control this.

So how does Windows handle this kind of file names? And what is the use of this? Thank you.

Comment: The directories really have different names, as shown by the `DIR` command. (You might also be able to find their real names if you look hard enough in Properties.) This is probably done with a hidden system file called `DESKTOP.INI` in each directory, which tells Windows how to present the directory. (Per-directory customizations like display icon are also specified in the `DESKTOP.INI` file.)

Comment: There is no `desktop.ini` though. I mentioned I don't see hidden files. I even tried `type desktop.ini` but just got a not-found error.

Comment: @G-Man I also mentioned that option in the question. I turned it off and I `cd` into one of the directories but still no `desktop.ini`.

Comment: It seems to be similar to the infamous [God Mode](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UnlockingWindows8GodModeAUsefulTrickButAlsoMysteriousNonsense.aspx) folder trick, not quite sure how they're doing it though, with the hiding.  Search your Registry for one/some of these GUIDs, I'd be interested to know what keys they existing in (if any).

Comment: I am going to guess that `Installer2` itself has certain properties enabled.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 When I said "I create and move a folder with a trailing GUID into `Installer2`" I did it quite casually, even a folder like `test.{}` will be hidden.